# Using Angular to bind a select dropdown to an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select dropdown in HTML that has strings for display and numbers as its value. Each number is the ID of a resource that can be queries via a REST HTTP URL.

How do I bind the changing selection state of a select to a property on an Angular controller? Is it correct to use ng-change? What's the most Angularian and declarative way of doing this?

Assume for now that the select is scoped to the same controller as the function that makes the REST request.

Comment: [http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04)

Comment: I'm not seeing that it matches what I need just quite. Perhaps I should simplify my question, I want a change in a select to trigger a function in the controller that includes the new value of the select. I think then the function can take that value and append it to a REST query. I can bind the select already to a property on the controller, but changing the property doesn't trigger a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `$watch` on the `ng-model` property in scope for the `select`.

```
$scope.selectModel='foo';
$scope.otherProperty= /* ....*/

$scope.$watch( 'selectModel', function(){
   $http.get(url, { keyName: $scope.selectModel).success(function(response) {
           $scope.otherProperty=response;
    });

})
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found that that the ng-change attribute will work as well.

Comment: as i prefaced..this is one way. I presented this one because can use `$watch` for many other uses within app and is extremely valuable tool in your angular arsenal

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, I agree your answer is better and broader, that's why I marked it accepted and upvoted it. I was just noticing that there is at least one other select specific way.

Comment: curious what other way is, I just started with angular not long ago, still figuring out variations

Comment: As I said, ng-change allows you to call a function on the controller, which in turn can make the AJAX call. I think yours is a better approach because at the moment I'm having issues with two way binding, going from model back to the view.